# SDL not rendering a screen on game window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl

I'm struggling to get a square to render on the game window with SDL. I have a two files, SZ_Player.h, and SZ.Player.cpp, and then the main of course. I have initialized the SZ_Player in the main as well by doing "SZ_Player examplePlayer", as well as including it by doing "include "SZ_Player.h".

I'm not exactly sure why it's not showing up, I have images below of the codes:

**SZ_Player.h**

```
#ifndef playerFile
#define playerFile

#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"

class SZ_Player
{
public:
    SZ_Player();
    ~SZ_Player();

    void Init();
    void Update();
    void Input();
    void Render(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer);
    SDL_Rect player;
    int x, y, height, width, R, G, B;
};

#endif
```

**SZ_Player.cpp**

```
#include "SZ_Player.h"

SZ_Player::SZ_Player()
{

}
SZ_Player::~SZ_Player()
{

}

void SZ_Player::Init()
{
    player.x = 70;
    player.y = 70;
    player.w = 100;
    player.h = 100;

    R = 255;
    G = 255;
    B = 255;
}

void SZ_Player::Update()
{

}

void SZ_Player::Input()
{

}

void SZ_Player::Render(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(pRenderer, R, G, B, 255);
    SDL_RenderDrawRect(pRenderer, &player);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL_mixer.h"

using namespace std;

#include "SZ_timer.h"
SZ_Timer aTimer;
const int DELTA_TIME = 10;
bool done = false;

#include "SZ_Player.h"
SZ_Player examplePlayer;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0);

    // Creates the game window
    SDL_Window* game_window = SDL_CreateWindow("Rise", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    // Creates the game render to draw on the game window.
    SDL_Renderer* game_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(game_window, 0, 0);

    // Game Loop
    while (!done)
    {
        aTimer.resetTicksTimer();

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game_renderer, 0, 0, 20, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
        SDL_RenderClear(game_renderer);
        examplePlayer.Render(game_renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(game_renderer);

        // If less time has passed than allocated block, wait difference
        if (aTimer.getTicks() < DELTA_TIME)
        {
            SDL_Delay(DELTA_TIME - aTimer.getTicks());
        }
    }
    SDL_Quit();

    // Exits program
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should print something if the SDL_Init() in main fails.

Comment: Why is `done` a global variable?

Comment: I always wonder how people even think of posting pictures of their code instead of simply copy paste it.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, any idea why it's not rendering?

Comment: You still did not copy and paste your code as text. You have to make it easy for people to duplicate your result. No one is going to type all this code in to help you for free. Also parts of the code are hidden by the size of the window.

Comment: I have added the code. @drescherjm

Comment: you need to setup a loop inside your "Game Loop" to poll events from SDL. Without it many platforms/backends wont be able to render anything.

Comment: You never called `SZ_Player::Init()` so your rectangle and colour are all-zeroes. Good time to start using debugging techniques.